# Programmatically Adding ImageViews in LinearLayout

Tags: android, imageview, android-linearlayout, android-imageview, android-custom-view

I'm Programmatically Creating Simple `LinearLayout` which has two Child(`Imageviews`) occupies the equal width, In this case the Rootview is CustomLayout(`SquareLinearLayout`).

**Here is the SquareLinearLayout** :

```
public class SquareLinearLayout extends LinearLayout {

    public SquareLinearLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public SquareLinearLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {

        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

        int orientation = getContext().getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;

        if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT || orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED) {

            int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
            int height = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(width, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
            setMeasuredDimension(width, height);

        } else {

            int height = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
            int width = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(height, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
            setMeasuredDimension(width, height);

        }

    }
}
```

**Related XML**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <com.customviews.SquareLinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lay_square"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ececec"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/lay_r_capture"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
        </LinearLayout>

    </com.customviews.SquareLinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Programmatically Adding the ImageView in LinearLayout**

```
lay_r_capture = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.lay_r_capture);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layparam = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
lay_r_capture.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
lay_r_capture.setWeightSum(2f);
lay_r_capture.setLayoutParams(layparam);

LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1f);
    lp.setMargins(8,8,8,8);

ImageView img1 = new ImageView(this);
Bitmap photo1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(ctx.getResources(), R.drawable.photo_1);
img1.setLayoutParams(lp);
img1.setImageBitmap(photo1);

ImageView img2 = new ImageView(this);
Bitmap photo2 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(ctx.getResources(), R.drawable.photo_2);
img2.setLayoutParams(lp);
img2.setImageBitmap(photo2);

lay_r_capture.addView(img1);
lay_r_capture.addView(img2);
```

**This Things not working as expected like** [image: this]

Output :

[image]

**Which Attributes or `LayoutParams` i'm missing ?**

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: it didn't work like expected , Let me Edit Question with Output Image.

Comment: Have a look on que again !

Comment: So you want empty space to be filled by image?

Comment: yes ! it's strange result with comparing to expected result !

Comment: The parent layout of your **SquareLinearLayout** is of height 0dp and weight 1, so give WRAP_CONTENT as its height and remove wieght

Comment: change height to match_parent in SquareLayout XML

Comment: no, change in it's parent `android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"` to `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`

Comment: @AkshayBhat'AB' i did it ! but there is nothing behaving like it has to be!

Comment: set different background color to each parent layout and check the output

Comment: @AkshayBhat'AB' you are right but the lay_r_capture (LinearLayout) fill the all space of SquareLinearLayout with pink color so there is nothing like as you think

Comment: Have you tried wrap_content as height of `lay_r_capture` layout

Comment: yes, i did all the things that you suggest !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133234/discussion-between-akshay-bhat-ab-and-hardik-kubavat).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are Programatically setting `MATCH_PARENT` as height here :

```
lay_r_capture = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.lay_r_capture);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layparam = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
lay_r_capture.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
lay_r_capture.setWeightSum(2f);
lay_r_capture.setLayoutParams(layparam);
```

So change it to `WRAP_CONTENT` like :

```
lay_r_capture = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.lay_r_capture);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layparam = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
lay_r_capture.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
lay_r_capture.setWeightSum(2f);
lay_r_capture.setLayoutParams(layparam);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//you can set imageView like  //img1.setImageResource(R.drawable.photo_2);    

lay_r_capture = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.lay_r_capture);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layparam = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    lay_r_capture.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    lay_r_capture.setWeightSum(2f);
    lay_r_capture.setLayoutParams(layparam);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1f);
        lp.setMargins(8,8,8,8);

    ImageView img1 = new ImageView(this);
    img1.setImageResource(R.drawable.photo_1);
    img1.setLayoutParams(lp);

    ImageView img2 = new ImageView(this);
    img2.setImageResource(R.drawable.photo_2);
    img2.setLayoutParams(lp);

    lay_r_capture.addView(img1);
    lay_r_capture.addView(img2);
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are facing is because of `SquareLinearLayout`. In `onMeasure()` of the `SquareLinearLayout`, you are changing the width and height of the view to achieve square type layout.

```
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {

        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

        int orientation = getContext().getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;

        //The below code will set width = height, to achieve square layout
        if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT || orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED) {

            int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
            int height = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(width, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
            setMeasuredDimension(width, height);

        } else {

            int height = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
            int width = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(height, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
            setMeasuredDimension(width, height);

        }
```

Comment: Thanks for your efforts but i want SquareLinearLayout as a root layout to achieve my result !